# Pass session variable as parameter into a SELECT query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is the session record for currently logged in user

```
username = Convert.ToString(Session["Username"]);
passward = Convert.ToString(Session["passward"]);
outlet   = Convert.ToString(Session["Outletid"]);
```

Here I am getting the values for all existing user's data but I need only the 
current user's data using outletid.

```
DataSet dsemp = obj.ReturnDataSet("Select DisplyBtnName,CName,Displaycolor from customermaster where CustSupFlag='S' and Flag='0'
    and outletid="????" order by 1");
```

How can I get the current logged in user outlet?

Comment: It looks like the question is incomplete and can't be answered unless you show us what fields `customermaster` has that can be related to `username` and `password`. (PS it is *password*, not *passward*)

Comment: oh sorry for less descriptions.. here is one common column "outletid" and i need to get data accordingly associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int outlet   = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Outletid"]);

DataSet dsemp = obj.ReturnDataSet("Select DisplyBtnName,CName,Displaycolor from customermaster where CustSupFlag='S' and Flag='0' and outletid="+ outlet +" order by 1");
```

Comment: Thanks @Ved, it is working fine but why i need to convert it in int?

Comment: No specific reason .you can keep datatype as per your requirement @PrashantKumar

Comment: if it resolves your issue. please mark it as solution @PrashantKumar.

Comment: i want a question to you in an scenario: In a project requirement through DDL username selected by the admin then the related values like (userid,type,password in '*' form should populate but in aspx pwd field declared as TextMode = password so how can i retrive it ?)

Comment: ASPX code :<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox> C# code: TextBox3.Text= dsusermaster.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
            TextBox3.Attributes["type"] = "password"; I tried it but won't work

Comment: Please note that building your querystring in this way is vulnerable to "sql injection". The usual way to prevent this is by using "parameters", but I do not know whether your `obj`  supports this.

Comment: @PrashantKumar If you could use that password, it means that you store it as plain text, readable for everyone that accesses your database. A big security risk!

Comment: @HansKesting Thanks for your suggestion, But there is only one Super admin for this application and what is the requirement: here super admin login and handle DB and APP too. but if any of the user forgot password or not able to login in his work at that time admin can get all details using username which ids in DDL, Here PWD should be in astrix format for admin too. Now admin just enter new pwd and share it with user after that user can change it (for that i have separate) through ChangePwd.aspx page.

Comment: @PrashantKumar don't use password mode for TextBox3 because here it is used only for display purpose and TextMode="Password" will not work for you. Instead write a method in your .cs file to replace each character of your password into "*" . and then assign to  TextBox3.